# What does the Reset Hub button on an Azure Virtual Hub do?

Tags: azure, azure-networking

Azure's Virtual Hub has a couple of buttons at the top: `Reset Router` and `Reset Hub`.
I've found some documentation on `Reset Router` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/virtual-wan/hub-settings#:%7E:text=can%20locate%20the-,Reset%20Router,-option%20by%20navigating) but so far cannot find anything on `Reset Hub`.

[image: The Reset Hub link on a Virtual Hub]

I'm trying to ascertain if Reset just means power-cycle/reboot; or if it clears all configuration / something like that.

I'm also trying to find out what the impact is on end users; i.e. do we lose all network connectivity whilst the reset is taking place (and if so, how long does a typical reset take), or is a new node brought up before the old one's taken down so that the reset is invisible to end users?

---

### Additional Context

Note: Looking into this because all the route tables in our hub are no longer displaying in the portal & many commands which touch route tables fail / the cause seems to be that when anything touchs the `defaultRouteTable` (e.g. `Get-AzResource -ResourceId 'id-of-the-default-root-table'`) we get a `503 Bad Gateway` error; querying other route tables all works; but if we try to list them rather than querying specificly named route tables, we again get a 503... So we're wondering if the issue is something in the Azure Management Layer / if that may be resolved by a "reset".

The resources themselves are working correctly - so whilst there's an issue managing our Azure resources, users are currently unimpacted by any network issues.

We have an MS incident open for the above... so the question  abour `Reset Hub` is as much about curiousity as resolving the issue... We've asked MS the same, but our ticket's still in its first few hours, so it will likely be a few days (given the weekend) before it gets to someone who can answer this.

Comment: Update: MS have now shared this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-wan/about-virtual-hub-routing#reset - which says that it brings the hub back to the correct provisioning state... Not yet clear whether this has any impact of this on existing connections / potential downtime...

Comment: if solved, add your own comment as an answer and accept it 24h later on please

Comment: Thanks @djdomi... so far I've got that link; but it doesn't say much on what to expect (i.e. it says that it brings the hub back to the correct provisoined state, but doesn't mention what impact this has on services relying on the hub (i.e. downtime)... When we try this for real, if there's been no better answers, I'll create an answer with feedback based on our real-world experience.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the docs what reset does
*Hub reset
Virtual hub Reset is available only in the Azure portal. Resetting provides you with a way to bring any failed resources such as route tables, hub router, or the virtual hub resource itself back to its rightful provisioning state. Consider resetting the hub prior to contacting Microsoft for support. This operation doesn't reset any of the gateways in a virtual hub.*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-wan/about-virtual-hub-routing#reset